# SQL Search Query show same results many times although it is only single time in my database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

**Project-**
Database name- test2

i have 2 tables in my database

**table1 contains**

```
Id  Name    Mobile  Email   
17  name1   1111    name1@test  
18  name2   2222    name2@test  
28  name3   3333    name3@test
```

**table2 contains**

```
Sr. Id  Paymobile   Month   Amount  Date    
1   28  3333        Jan     200     2021-01-06  
2   28  3333        Feb     400     2021-02-06  
3   28  3333        Apr     600     2021-04-08  
4   17  1111        Mar     400     2021-03-05  
6   18  2222        Aug     100     2021-08-27  
7   17  1111        Jun     600     2021-06-21
```

table1 has single and unique records,
table2 has include payment history so the id and mobile have multiple times.

**What i Want**
If i search the mobile on or email id then it will also give the results in two tables
like 1st table show ID,Name,Mobile,Email from table1
AND
2nd table show Month,Amount,Date from table2.
all is good but there is one issue which is mention below.

**Issue**
when i search the mobile no. 3333 or 2222 in my webpage then it show both results in two table as i want like table1 show Id,Name,Mobile,Email from table1
AND
2nd table show Month,Amount,Date from table2.

But the Main Problem is that it will show Id,Name,Mobile,Email many times although it have single records in my database. like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBipK.png)

****My Configuration****

**1-form.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- (A) SEARCH FORM -->
    <form method="post" action="1-form.php">
      <h1>SEARCH FOR USERS</h1>
      <input type="text" name="search" required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
 
    <table>
    <style>
        table { font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
    }
    td, th {border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
    }
    </style>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Mobile</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
<?php
// (B2) DISPLAY RESULTS 
?>
<?php
// (B) PROCESS SEARCH WHEN FORM SUBMITTED
if (isset($_POST["search"])) {
    // (B1) SEARCH FOR USERS
    require "2-search.php";
?>
  
<?php
    // (B2) DISPLAY RESULTS 
    if(isset($_POST) && array_key_exists('search',$_POST)) {
        if (count($results) > 0) { foreach ($results as $r) {
?>  
            <tr>  
                <td> <?php echo $r['Id'] ;?> </td>                
                <td> <?php echo $r['Name'] ;?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $r['Mobile'] ;?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $r['Email'] ;?> </td>
            </tr>
<?php
        }
    }
} else { 
    echo "No results found"; }
}
?>


  </table>
  <p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
<?php
// (B2) DISPLAY RESULTS
if (count($results) > 0) { 
    foreach ($results as $r) {
?>  
        <tr>                  
            <td> <?php echo $r['Month'] ;?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $r['Amount'] ;?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $r['Date'] ;?> </td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
} else { 
    echo "No results found"; 
}
?>
</table>
</html>
```

and

**2-search.php**

```
<?php
// (A) DATABASE CONFIG - CHANGE TO YOUR OWN!
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "test2");
define("DB_CHARSET", "utf8");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");

// (B) CONNECT TO DATABASE
try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";charset=".DB_CHARSET.";dbname=".DB_NAME,
        DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        ]
    );
} catch (Exception $ex) { 
    exit($ex->getMessage()); 
}

// (C) SEARCH
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT table1.*, table2.* 
                        FROM table1 
                        INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.Id = table2.Id 
                        WHERE `Name` LIKE ? OR `Mobile` LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(["%".$_POST["search"]."%", "%".$_POST["search"]."%"]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (isset($_POST["ajax"])) { 
    echo json_encode($results); 
}
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: sure i will look at Good code indentation. and Thankyou for give me a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By mixing multiple steps and method by the help of stack over flow and w3school.

Now my New Configuration is listed below

**1-form.php**

```
<style>
table {
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

td, th {
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- (A) SEARCH FORM -->
    <form method="post" action="1-form.php">
      <h1>SEARCH FOR USERS</h1>
      <input type="text" name="search" required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>

    <?php
    // (B) PROCESS SEARCH WHEN FORM SUBMITTED
    if (isset($_POST["search"])) {
      // (B1) SEARCH FOR USERS
      require "2-search.php";
      ?>

      <table>

        <tr>
      
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Mobile</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
      // (B2) DISPLAY RESULTS
      if (count($results) > 0) { foreach ($results as $r) {
      ?>  
      
      <tr>                  
                <td> <?php echo $r['Id'] ;?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $r['Name'] ;?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $r['Mobile'] ;?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $r['Email'] ;?> </td>
                </tr>
        <?php

        
      }} else { echo "No results found"; }
    }
    ?>
    </table>







<p>
  Billing Details
  <p>

<?php
    // (B) PROCESS SEARCH WHEN FORM SUBMITTED
    if (isset($_POST["search"])) {
      // (B1) SEARCH FOR USERS
      
      ?>

      <table>

        <tr>
      
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Mobile</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
      // (B2) DISPLAY RESULTS
      if (count($results2) > 0) { foreach ($results2 as $r2) {
      ?>  
      
      <tr>                  
                <td> <?php echo $r2['Id'] ;?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $r2['Month'] ;?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $r2['Amount'] ;?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $r2['Date'] ;?> </td>
                </tr>
        <?php

        
      }} else { echo "No results found"; }
    }
    
    ?>
</table>


  </body>
</html>
```

**2-search.php**

```
<?php
// (A) DATABASE CONFIG - CHANGE TO YOUR OWN!
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "test2");
define("DB_CHARSET", "utf8");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");

// (B) CONNECT TO DATABASE
try {
  $pdo = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";charset=".DB_CHARSET.";dbname=".DB_NAME,
    DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, [
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ]
  );
} catch (Exception $ex) { exit($ex->getMessage()); }

// (C) SEARCH
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `Id` LIKE ? OR `Mobile` LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(["%".$_POST["search"]."%", "%".$_POST["search"]."%"]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (isset($_POST["ajax"])) { echo json_encode($results); }

$pdo->connection = null;
$pdo=null;





try {
  $pdo2 = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";charset=".DB_CHARSET.";dbname=".DB_NAME,
    DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, [
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ]
  );
} catch (Exception $ex) { exit($ex->getMessage()); }

// (C) SEARCH
$stmt2 = $pdo2->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `Id` LIKE ? OR `Paymobile` LIKE ?");
$stmt2->execute(["%".$_POST["search"]."%", "%".$_POST["search"]."%"]);
$results2 = $stmt2->fetchAll();
if (isset($_POST["ajax"])) { echo json_encode($results2); }

$pdo2->connection = null;
$pdo2=null;
```

Answer (score 2):

An INNER JOIN will show all matching rows for both tables. If you hit ID 28 which is present 1 time in table1 but 3 times in table2, you will get 3 rows in total.

You can add a `GROUP BY Id` to your query or make 2 queries - one for each table - instead of 1 query with an INNER JOIN.

Comment: After reading your answer i try to do it using Group BY Id but after this i am not abel to fetch all payment records from table2 for Id 28 . currently i have total 3 records for id 28 these all three records have unique payment month, amount and date. all these three records month, amount, date are required.

Comment: and one more i don't know how to make 2 queries for one project.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the keyword `DISTINCT` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.*, table2.* 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.Id = table2.Id 
WHERE `Name` LIKE ? OR `Mobile` LIKE ?
```

Comment: I already try `DISTINCT` in my code but not work it also show same records multiple times. may be due to i have make a `INNER JOIN` so it will not working here.